# Django foreign key reference from another model

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

I have following models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   """books = Attribute which allows an access to books from this author"""
   class Meta:
      ordering = ['name']


class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   class Meta:
      ordering = ['name']
```

How I can make an attribute to Author, which allows me to get an access to its books?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to create a new attribute in `Author`. You can get the books written by a specific author by following the `ForeignKey` relationship backwards as follows:

```
author = Author.objects.get(name='George Orwell')
books = author.book_set.all()
```

The `book_set` function is created by default by Django when you create the `ForeignKey` relationship between `Book` and `Author`.